# error - ../node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html after installing sqlite3 in nextron app

Tags: sqlite, next.js, electron, better-sqlite3

```
../node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>
```

Getting this error after I installed sqlite3 with my nextron app

After this I start getting the following error

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // This script needs to be compatible with PowerShell v2 to run on Windows 2008R2 and Windows 7.
| 
> using System;
| using System.Text;
| using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

After that starts getting this error import error

```
Error: /home/Ankit/Projects/test/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/package.jsondoes not exist

> 1 | const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose()
                     ^
```

Don't know how to encounter this, any help would be better, thankyou in advance...

First error get resolved if I add the following code to my next.config.js file

```
config.module.rules.push({ test: /.html$/, use: "html-loader", });
```

I resolved the second error too by adding the following code to **next.config.js** file

```
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.cs$/,
    use: "raw-loader",
});
```

**Also used electron-builder**

Also used a substitute **better-sqlite3** but getting error of **undefined indexOf** on initialization.

I'm using:
node v16.20.0
sqlite3 v5.1.6
@mapbox/node-pre-gyp v1.0.10

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load a binary Node.js addon - `node-sqlite3` which depends on `@mapbox/node-pre-gyp`. Depending on what exactly you are doing, this may be impossible.

First of all, these modules do not work in the browser. In the case of Electron, they will work only in the Node.js process.

However in your particular case you also have `webpack` - probably as part of `next.js`. `webpack` tries to make a bundle out of your `node_modules` and chokes on the code that finds and loads the shared library.

You will have to manually tell `webpack` to treat the shared library - usually a file ending in `.node` - as an `external` and to leave the `require()` in your code. Look in the `index.js` of `node-sqlite3`. You may have to edit it, so that the path to the `.node` file is fixed instead of being autodetected - this `webpack` cannot handle.

Then, if your code is executed in the Node.js environment, it will be able to load the library. If it is loaded in the UI render process, it will fail.

I just did something very similar with `next.js` this way:

`next.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.externals.push('everything-json');
    return config;
  }
};
```

(I am using my own binary module that also uses `@mapbox/node-pre-gyp` called `everything-json`)